# How to get url of website with nodejs & cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

URL1 is used to scrape a website. But URL1 is not the destination URL. I got redirected from URL1 to URL2.

Is there any possibility to get the value of URL2?

window.location or document.location result in ".... is not defined"

Comment: Could you please share your code block that does the actual request and gets the response. I just wanted to know how you are handling it. If you are using `request` module for example, you have `uri` object within your response object. That'd do the trick.

Comment: Thanks!

I was looking for:

`response.request.uri.href`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [request](https://github.com/request/request).

> followRedirect - follow HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default:
> true). This property can also be implemented as function which gets
> response object as a single argument and should return true if
> redirects should continue or false otherwise.
>
> followAllRedirects -
> follow non-GET HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default: false)
>
> maxRedirects - the maximum number of redirects to follow (default: 10)
>
> removeRefererHeader - removes the referer header when a redirect
> happens (default: false). Note: if true, referer header set in the
> initial request is preserved during redirect chain.